# Xamarin Forms ListView grouping bind issue

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, grouping

I have been trying to play around Xamarin Forms for a while and then came across to the Listview Grouping. I am not getting done its showing blank list. Please give me help to find where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance

However, My class domain looks like:

```
public class LineItemTaxDto 
    {
        public int InvoiceLineItemId { get; set; }
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public int TaxId { get; set; }
        public decimal TaxRate { get; set; }
        public decimal TaxAmount { get; set; }
        public string TaxName { get; set; }    
    }
```

My View Model property look like

```
 public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<LineItemTaxDto>>> ReceiptTaxList { get; set; }
```

My expecting result look like:

[image]

My xaml code below

```
          <ListView x:Name="TaxListView"
                Grid.Row="2" 
                Grid.Column="0" 
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Invoice.ReceiptTaxList}" 
                IsGroupingEnabled="true">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Key}" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Text="{Binding TaxName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="22" FontFamily="{x:Static resources:Fonts.ArialMTFont}" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0,5,0,5" />

                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TaxAmount, Converter={Helpers:CurrencyAmountConverter}}" FontSize="22" FontFamily="{x:Static resources:Fonts.ArialMTFont}" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

**EDIT**

I am set value in view will appear method

```
Invoice.ReceiptTaxList = Invoice.InvoiceLineItems.Select(x => { return new KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<LineItemTaxDto>>(x.TaxName, x.LineItemTaxes); });
```

The value was set properly

Comment: Whats is the 'Key' property? And how do you fill it? Can you post the code? Maybe I can help you

Comment: Please check my question again I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this tricky code not using grouping but now its work as expected

**My ViewModel Code**

```
var TaxList = Invoice.InvoiceLineItems.Where(x => x.TaxId > 1).GroupBy(y=>y.TaxId > 1).Select(x =>
 {
    return new KeyValuePair<LineItemTaxDto, ObservableCollection<LineItemTaxDto>>(new LineItemTaxDto()
    {
        InvoiceLineItemId = x.First().Id,
        InvoiceId = x.First().InvoiceId,
        TaxId = x.First().TaxId,
        TaxRate = x.First().TaxRate,
        TaxAmount = x.Sum(a=>a.TaxAmount),
        TaxName = taxlabel + " (" + x.First().TaxName + ")"
    }, x.First().LineItemTaxes);
 });

var taxes = new ObservableCollection<LineItemTaxDto>();
foreach (var tax in TaxList.GroupBy(tax => tax.Key.TaxId).Select(grp => grp.First()))
{
    taxes.Add(tax.Key);
    foreach (var subtax in tax.Value.Where(x => x.TaxId > 0))
    {
        taxes.Add(subtax);
    }
}

Invoice.ReceiptTaxList = taxes;
```

**My Xaml Code**

```
<ListView 
x:Name="TaxListView"
ItemsSource="{Binding Invoice.ReceiptTaxList}" 
Grid.Row="2" 
Grid.Column="0" 
Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
SeparatorVisibility="None"
HasUnevenRows="false"
RowHeight="35"
>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TaxName}" FontSize="22" FontFamily="{x:Static resources:Fonts.ArialMTFont}" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TaxAmount, Converter={Helpers:CurrencyAmountConverter}}" FontSize="22" FontFamily="{x:Static resources:Fonts.ArialMTFont}" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,5,0,5" />
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score -1):

You must use a list of list as items source on listview to get it working. I recommend you to create a class with the properties you want to show at header like this:

```
public class TaxesObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T> // Think about to implement INotifyPropertyChanged too, I guess it will be usefull
{
    public TaxesObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection, string taxGroupName) : base(collection)
    {
        TaxGroupName = taxGroupName;
    }
    
    private bool taxGroupName;
    public bool TaxGroupName
    {
        get { return taxGroupName; }
        set { taxGroupName = value; }
    }
}
```

In your view model:

```
public IEnumerable<TaxesObservableCollection<LineItemTaxDto>> ReceiptTaxList { get; set; }
```

Your ListView:

```
(...) // The rest of it as you did
<ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Label Text="{Binding TaxGroupName}" />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
(...) // The rest of it as you did
```

And you fill it this way:

```
Invoice.ReceiptTaxList = Invoice.InvoiceLineItems.Select(x => { return new TaxesObservableCollection<LineItemTaxDto>(x.LineItemTaxes, x.TaxName); }).ToList();
```

It should works, please let me know if is that what you wanted.